# How to assert class object using pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, assert

I want to assert the class object with hard coded known value, with that need to test if the class objected created or not.

Function:

```
def function_name():
    parameter = None
    car = "audi"
    if car== "audi":
        """ calling another function"""
        file = "c:/desktop/test.txt"
        parameter = other_class(file)
    else:
        print("car is not audi")
    return parameter

class other_class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=file
        self.y = {}
    ---having other methods in the class---
```

and the test is :

```
def test_function_name():
    parameter = function_name
    expected_result = "<function_name object at 0x000002081256CBE0>"
    print(f"expected_result: {expected_result}") 
    assert str(parameter) == expected_result
```

Every time id `0x000002081256CBE0`from the object is change then how to assert it with hard coded known value

Comment: That string value for `expected_result` is not guaranteed to be reproducible. You need some access to the *actual* return value of `other_function`, then assert that `parameter = function_name()` equals that object.

Comment: Understood, we need to do it without using the function call, need to do with hard coded known value

Comment: `<function_name object at ...>` is not a known value. That's the output of the function's `__repr__` method, which in CPython contains a memory address that isn't necessarily fixed. (If you aren't actually *calling* `function_name`, what exactly are you testing?)

Comment: I think you want `parameter = function_name()`, i.e. assert the return value from the function you test, not the function object itself. It doesn't make sense to assert the function object

Comment: And because `car` is hardcoded in the `function_name` the return value would be always  `None`. It makes sense that your function takes `car` as argument, then you can have 2 tests - pass `audi`, assert return value is `None`, then second test - for different value - assert return value is not `None` or assert the expected value as returned from `other_function()` for that value of `car`.

Comment: just want to test that `other_function()` class got called or not

Comment: _test that other_function() class got called or not_ - in your current setup, that means to test that the result returned from calling `function_name()` is not `None`. Or testing that returned value is instance of type `other_class`

Answer (score 0):

To check that returned objects are of the correct type, you should use the `isinstance` function. Let's suppose you have several types of cars, each represented by a class. You also have a class `Car` from which they all inherit.

```py
class Car():
    pass

class Audi(Car):
    pass

class Mercedes(Car):
    pass

...

def other_function():
    audi = Audi()
    # do something else
    # and return the object (not a string representing the object)
    return audi

def function_name(car):
    parameter = None

    if car == "audi":
        """calling another function"""
        parameter = other_function()
    else:
        print("car is not audi")
    return parameter
```

and in your test, you would check for example the type of the car, like this:

```
from XXX import function_name, Audi

def test_function_name():
    parameter = function_name(car="audi")
    assert isinstance(parameter, Audi)  # check that parameter is of type "Audi"
```

Note: Instead of checking the type, you could check whatever value you want: `assert parameter.whatever_attribute == "foobar"`.

---

If you wish to reformat your test to check different values for `car`, you can use [`pytest.mark.parametrize`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html).

Comment: Just edited the question requesting you, please check
not checking for car, testing for `other_class()` is successfully getting called or not

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to check if `other_class` is called. A quick near-equivalent is to check if `function_name` *reutrns* an instance of `other_class`:

```
def test_function_name():
    obj = function_name()
    assert isinstance(obj, other_class)
```

If you want to ensure that `function_name` actually called `other_class` to produce the return value, mock `other_class` and provide a fixed return
value that you can assert is what `function_name` returns.

```
def test_function_name():
    expected = object()
    with unittest.mock.patch('other_class', return_value=expected) as mock_oc:
        obj = function_name()

    assert obj is expected
```